# Can I disable SSH last-login and MOTD on a per-user basis?

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions

I'm aware you can disable last-login and message-of-the-day messages when starting SSH sessions by having `PrintLastLog no` and `PrintMotd no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

However, I don't have permission to modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in the system I'm accessing. Is there a way to set `PrintLastLog no` and `PrintMotd no` for my local user only?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can, add the `Match User` directive to your sshd_config file like so:

```
Match User root 
    PrintlastLog no
    PrintMotd no
```

The `Match` directive also works for `Group` and `Address` to match for GEOS/Unix group and IP Address retrospectively.

**Update:**

As a per user basis without access to the sshd_config then you would just create an empty file in `$HOME/.hushlogin` which would prevent bash in interactive mode to output these alerts. This also works under other systems that use `login(1)` such as telnet and screen sessions.

**Update 2:**

To surpress the `Banner` output from sshd on a per session basis use `ssh -q <host>`or include `LogLevel quiet` in your ~/.ssh/config

Comment: OP said he cannot modify /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: Thanks @MariusMatutiae for pointing that out. I've updated my answer to account for that.

Comment: `~/.hushlogin` suppressed the motd and last login messages. :D Bonus points if you can disable the banner as defined by `Banner /etc/issue` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: Thanks @XAleXOwnZX I completely forgot about that. I've updated the answer to include the Banner suppression.

Answer (score 4):

Not all OpenSSH implementations as those in Ubuntu allow *PrintMotd* or *PrintlastLog* in *Match User* section.

One may find [this askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537521/set-user-or-group-specific-motd-in-ssh) usefull with some workaround if s/he got error like:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 97: Directive 'PrintMotd' is not allowed within a Match block
```